# Two Click Events for speech bubbles

Tags: jquery, click

i have a problem with jQuery and the click function. I want edit a speech bubble plugin from "http://gdakram.github.com/JQuery-Tooltip-Plugin". Here you can see, if you mouseover the button, it opens a speech bubble. I want this function with clicks, not with mouseover.
My problem is, that this script is too complicated for me… this is one part (the js-data) from the website:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.tooltip = function(settings) {
// Configuration setup
config = { 
'dialog_content_selector' : 'div.tooltip_description',
'animation_distance' : 50,
'opacity' : 0.85,*/
'arrow_left_offset' : 70,
'arrow_top_offset' : 50,
'arrow_height' : 20,
'arrow_width' : 20,
'animation_duration_ms' : 300,
**'event_in':'click',** 
'hover_delay' : 0,
**'event_out': 'click',** 
};
```

Event in and event out didn’t work together… any ideas, what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

This is rough, but should work — build your own 'toggle' like method:

```
 config = { 
       'dialog_content_selector' : 'div.tooltip_description',
       'animation_distance' : 50,
       'opacity' : 0.85,
       'arrow_left_offset' : 70,
       'arrow_top_offset' : 50,
       'arrow_height' : 20,
       'arrow_width' : 20,
       'animation_duration_ms' : 300,
       '_event_' : 'click' 

      //'event_in':'mouseover',
      //'event_out':'mouseout',
      //'hover_delay' : 0
    }; 

   if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

 /**
  * Apply interaction to all the matching elements
  **/

 this.each(function() {

     toggleTip(this);   

 });

 /**
  * Positions the dialog box based on the target
  * element's location
  **/

 function toggleTip(tip) {  

    var count = 1;

    $(tip).bind(config._event_, function(e){

        e.stopPropagation();

        _hide(tip);

            count++ % 2 ? _show(tip) : _hide(tip);

     });

   };
```

In order for this to be truly effective you would need to re-think the _show() and _hide() functions.

Answer (score 0):

In this they are write a code to show and hide the tool tip using mouse over and mouse out 
so the click is not working please try with this

```
click for tooltip show 
mousemove for tooltip hide

(function($) {

    $.fn.tooltip = function(settings) {
    // Configuration setup
    config = { 
    'dialog_content_selector' : 'div.tooltip_description',
    'animation_distance' : 50,
    'opacity' : 0.85,*/
    'arrow_left_offset' : 70,
    'arrow_top_offset' : 50,
    'arrow_height' : 20,
    'arrow_width' : 20,
    'animation_duration_ms' : 300,
    'event_in':'click',
    'event_out':'mousemove'
    };
```

event_out may be `'mousemove'` or '`mouseleave'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That’s possible, but what if i want to click on a hyperlink in the speech bubble? So it’s unpossible to click, because of mouseleave or something like that. Any (other) ideas?

Comment: If you want hyperlink on speech bubbles means when will you hide the speech bubble?

Comment: then change the event like 'event_in':'mouseover',       'event_out':'click'

Comment: I mean, that a text appears, when i’m clicking on a button to open a speech bubble. The spech bubble contains a text and 2 words linked to another website. So it’s a information with "more information" via link

Comment: Ya, It's ok. then when will you hide your tool tip

Comment: »'event_in':'mouseover', 'event_out':'click'« seems pretty, but not perfect… it appears before i can close it with the click event… that’s a little bit… "ugly"… sorry for the circumstances. No way to change it to two click events?

Comment: then you have to write a new one for your requirement

Comment: Ok, you mean a new js-file for the speech bubble?

Comment: Wuaaah, i need help *run in circle*

Comment: Have a temporary variable by clicking the button assign some value to the temporary value, then check if it has default value means show the speech bubble otherwise hide if u want two click means

Comment: Okay, but how can i go ouside of this code? i can't understand the synatx in this case. What about .bind()? The Code continue with: *see on the top*

Comment: It's time taken process. It requires more changes in the file

Comment: Okay, but how can i do this kind of stuff? Can ou help me a lil’ bit?

Comment: Hmm… somebody have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

»'event_in':'mouseover', 'event_out':'click'« seems pretty, but not perfect… it appears before i can close it with the click event… that’s a little bit… "ugly"… sorry for the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

     /**
      * Apply interaction to all the matching elements
      **/
     this.each(function() {
       var hoverTimer;
       $(this).bind(config.event_in,function(){
        _hide(this);
         var ele = this;
         hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() { _show(ele); }, config.hover_delay)
       })
       .bind(config.event_out,function(){
         clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
         _hide(this);
       })
     });
```